# Conduit pipeline has strange execution times

Tags: haskell, conduit

I'm testing the performance of this recursive Haskell function, which repeatedly sums the first 100000000 integers of an infinite list (using a Conduit pipeline) and prints the elapsed time of each execution:

```hs
import Conduit
import Data.Time.Clock

evaluate_listC 0 = return ()
evaluate_listC i = do
    startTime <- getCurrentTime
    print $ runConduitPure $ yieldMany [1..] .| takeC 100000000 .| sumC
    endTime <- getCurrentTime
    print $ diffUTCTime endTime startTime
    evaluate_listC (i-1)
```

Compiling (with -O flag) and running the code, and iterating the function 10 times, I obtain the following execution times:

```
38.2066878s
4.3696857s
1.3367605s
0.9950032s
0.9399968s
0.9039936s
0.9079987s
0.9119587s
0.9090151s
0.8749654s
```

Why does the first iteration (and also the second) take more time while the following ones are incredibly faster?

Comment: A big component is probably caching; the first iteration has to actually compute the first 100000000 terms of the infinite list, but they remain in memory for the following iterations.

Comment: Something's fishy. I used `takeC (100000000+i)` to try to avoid caching (without success). With `-O0`, I get slow code (~18s each loop) which runs on ~5MB. With `-O2`, I get much faster loops with the effect shown above (10s the first one ,0.5s the second), using a whopping 5GB (!!!) resident memory. I had to use `Int` instead of the default `Integer` to prevent dying from OOM. Looks like caching, but caching is a quite wrong optimization in this case.

Comment: What exact test program / compiler flags are you using, and what version of GHC and Conduit are giving you these numbers?  With GHC 8.6.4 (using `-O2`) and Conduit 1.3.1.1, and the main program `main = evaluate_listC 10`, I'm seeing the first iteration run in constant memory and complete in under 2 secs with following iterations using a memoized value (i.e., all running in a few microseconds).  Downgrading to Conduit 1.3.0 (the earliest version with a `Conduit` convenience module), the first iteration slows down to 4.2 secs, but I can't see how to make it any slower than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, I can't duplicate these slow performance numbers, but I'm pretty sure I know what's going on.  If you provide some additional detail that allows me to duplicate the issue, I can update the answer.

Most likely, the list `[1..]` (or perhaps some larger expression involving this list) is being "lifted" as a constant applicative form (CAF) to top level.  As the list is generated during that first iteration, it's kept around as a "permanent" heap object for future iterations.

The first iteration takes a long time in **part** because it's allocating and generating the list, though because of GHC's "bump allocator", allocation is extremely fast, and actually generating the list probably only takes a few seconds.  Most of the time is likely spent garbage collecting.  GC time scales with the size of the "important" stuff that needs to be rescued (copied) from the bump allocator, and you're building a big, permanent list here.

Later iterations are much faster because they can run the Conduit summation over the existing list.  This probably involves some allocation for intermediate results, but most of them don't stick around, so there's much less to GC and the iterations are fast.

The reason the second and third iterations are a little slower than later iterations has to do with GHC's generational garbage collector.  Initially, both the permanent big list and other semi-permanent (e.g., needed only for a short time or for the current iteration) heap objects are copied out of the bump allocator.  Further garbage collection involves re-copying the same permanent list while allowing expired semi-permanent objects to be collected.  Eventually, the list gets promoted to the next generation, while all the non-list objects stay in the first generation.

Once the permanent list and semi-permanent "other objects" have been fully separated into different generations, the list no longer needs to be recopied during GC of the first generation, and iteration times settle down to around a second.